# psql: weird error output encoding on Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, windows, character-encoding, psql

Whenever I make a syntax error in psql, no matter what the problem is, psql shows only:

```
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xd0 0x9e in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"
```

without specifying the issue.

I am doing it on localhost.

I have tried changing the codepage to utf8 (via `chcp 65001`) and using `SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'utf8'` in psql itself. After that, errors are shown, but in strange encoding. I need it to show errors in English.

Error output I get after setting `chcp 65001` and using `SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'utf8'`:

[image: Error output I get after setting chcp 65001 and using "SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'utf8'"]

Error output I get without doing both of those:

[image: Error output I get without doing both of those]

EDIT: By running "\encoding UTF8" and "set lc_messages to 'en_us.utf-8';", it now shows errors in proper encoding. Thanks to Jorge Campos.

Comment: Quick google on those chars: https://www.appsloveworld.com/postgresql/100/218/why-does-psql-throw-error-character-with-byte-sequence-0xd0-0x9e-in-encoding-ut?expand_article=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have configured PostgreSQL to send Russian error messages, don't set your client encoding to `WIN1252`, because Cyrillic letters cannot be converted to that encoding.

You should set `lc_messages = C` in `postgresql.conf` and reload PostgreSQL to get English error messages.